# Not able to see file after creating it using docker command and committing the changes

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, dockerfile, docker-compose, docker-registry

I created docker container with name "task1".

I execute a shell command which creates a file foo.txt containing the word "hello".

I commit the docker container "task1"

I enter into the docker container "task1" in interactive mode with -it command

But I do not see the file "foo.txt" . I am expecting it because I have committed the container.
However, when I just pass "ls" command and execute it in the same container "task1", it shows the file "foo.txt".

What is the problem here? The below is the console detail where I am trying the above activities. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
 ~/G/S/d/d/H/test_io   master ±  docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
35784a56ffa3        task1               "/bin/bash"              5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds                                 task2
eb03c7b89e36        task1               "/bin/bash"              6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                                 clever_bell
352c6f8f1ff2        registry:2          "/bin/registry /etc/d"   10 days ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry

~/G/S/d/d/H/test_io   master ±  docker exec -it eb03c7b89e36 script /dev/null -c "echo 'Hello' > foo.txt"
    Script started, file is /dev/null
    Script done, file is /dev/null




  ~/G/S/d/d/H/test_io   master ±  docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
    35784a56ffa3        task1               "/bin/bash"              2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                                 task2
    eb03c7b89e36        task1               "/bin/bash"              8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes                                 clever_bell
    352c6f8f1ff2        registry:2          "/bin/registry /etc/d"   10 days ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry



   ~/G/S/d/d/H/test_io   master ±  docker commit eb03c7b89e36
    6d8666dc72caa36f436c46fe65e5beb6a1421ea27867153658303e430a33f126



   ~/G/S/d/d/H/test_io   master ±  docker run -it task1
    root@aad8db09c5fe:/# ls
    bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
    root@aad8db09c5fe:/# exit
    exit



  ~/G/S/d/d/H/test_io   master ±  docker exec -it eb03c7b89e36 ls
    bin   dev  foo.txt  lib    media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
    boot  etc  home     lib64  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var

 ~/G/S/d/d/H/test_io   master ±  docker start clever_bell
    clever_bell

 ~/G/S/d/d/H/test_io   master ±  docker run -it task1
    root@4bfba10c7c49:/# ls
    bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
    root@4bfba10c7c49:/# exit
    exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`docker commit <container>`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) does not alter the container's image in any way; it simply creates a *new* image separate from the original image.  If you want the `test1` image to be updated, you need to specify a name for the new image: `docker commit <container> test1`.

Comment: It works . I can also pass any new image name instead of test1 and it creates a new copy of the image with the committed change. Thanks.